# Python input from a <pre> tag

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, file-io

So I am writing some code in Python 2.7 to pull some information from a website, pull the relevant data from that set, then format that data in a way that is more useful. Specifically, I am wanting to take information from a html `<pre>` tag, put it into a file, turn that information in the file into an array (using numpy), and then do my analysis from that. I am stuck on the "put into a file" part. It seems that when I put it into a file, it is a 1x1 matrix or something and so it won't do what I hope it will. On an attempt previous to the code sample below, the error I got was: `IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0` I had the index for array just to test if it would provide output from what I have so far.

Here is my code so far:

```
#Pulling data from GFS lamps

from lxml import html
import requests
import numpy as np

ICAO = raw_input("What station would you like GFS lamps data for? ")

page = requests.get('http://www.nws.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/lamp/getlav.pl?sta=' + ICAO)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
Lamp = tree.xpath('//pre/text()') #stores class of //pre html element in list Lamp
gfsLamps = open('ICAO', 'w') #stores text of Lamp into a new file
gfsLamps.write(Lamp[0])

array = np.genfromtxt('ICAO') #puts file into an array

array[5]
```

You can use KOGD as the ICAO to test this. As is, I get `Value Error: Some Errors were detected` and it lists Lines 2-23 (Got 26 columns instead of 8). What is the first step that I am doing wrong for what I want to do? Or am I just going about this all wrong?

Comment: Please check if my answer helped you or is there any problem you are getting .

Comment: @iamnotgoogle So the issues I was having before are gone, but I am not getting what I am looking for, or i am not handling it right.  If I do `array[0]` or `array[1]` there is no output nor are there errors. If i do anything greater than that, it says `IndexError: list index out of range` . I decided to try the print function to see what it can tell me about the array, based on the code you gave me. I got this: `[array(['I'], 
      dtype='|S1'), array(['C'], 
      dtype='|S1'), array(['A'], 
      dtype='|S1'), array(['O'], 
      dtype='|S1')]`  However, the letters change

Comment: @iamnotgoogle Those letters are I instead of L, and a, m, p, instead of C A, and O.

Comment: that is just the filename, you have given ICAO in your question so i just used that. I have executed the code with the line i have wrote and it is giving the required output. I will add the whole code in my answer so you can see if you got anything wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't in the putting data into the file part, its getting it out using genfromtxt. The problem is that genfromtxt is a very rigid function, mostly needs complete data unless you specify lots of options to skip columns and rows. Use this one instead:

```
arrays = [np.array(map(str, line.split())) for line in open('ICAO')]
```

The arrays variable will contain array of each line which contains each individual element in that line seperated by a space, for ex if your line has the following data:

```
a b cdef 124
```

the array for this line will be:

```
['a','b','cdef','124']
```

arrays will contain array of each line like this, which can be processed as you wish further.
So complete code is:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import numpy as np

ICAO = raw_input("What station would you like GFS lamps data for? ")

page = requests.get('http://www.nws.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/lamp/getlav.pl?sta=' + ICAO)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
Lamp = tree.xpath('//pre/text()') #stores class of //pre html element in list Lamp
gfsLamps = open('ICAO', 'w') #stores text of Lamp into a new file
gfsLamps.write(Lamp[0])
gfsLamps.close()
array = [np.array(map(str, line.split())) for line in open('ICAO')]
print array
```

Comment: I didn't close the file after I wrote to it. That is the only difference I can see. It works now. Thank you!

Comment: @SamuelSmith Oh right forgot about that, can't open the file if it wasn't closed :D